# object with curve modifier doesn't work properly

Tags: bezier-curves

So I decided to learn about curves and after making a curve I added resized cube with a modifier "curve" with set object of the previously mentioned curve and then I changed the length and shape of a curve. After that, the end result of a cube performs differently than I think it should. For some reason it's not on the curve, it's under it like in the picture, and moving the curve makes modified cube act in unexpected ways.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). When using curve modifier, origin position is important. It works best when both origins are in the exact same place.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. Do you know perhaps how to connect end for the array with the beginning like in the picture? http://prntscr.com/r4k6xp

Comment: For this purpose better to use beveling. You can bevel a curve with an other so just make a rectangle shaped curve and add as a bevel object to the other. You can find it in the Curve Properties.